# Does CDN know which website the client is visiting when fetching jquery.min.js or other resource from CDN?

Tags: javascript, cdn

Can CDN create some kind of statistics by tracking visitors of my site or they download needed libraries without sharing the URL of the page they visit ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they can use the [referer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) header field:

> The HTTP referer (originally a misspelling of referrer) is an HTTP
>   header field that identifies the address of the webpage (i.e. the URI
>   or IRI) that linked to the resource being requested. By checking the
>   referrer, the new webpage can see where the request originated.

The field is part of the request header which could look like this, for example, reloading this page will show that this link to googleapis (see console <kbd>F12</kbd> and the network tab):

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
```

Sent this request header:

```
Host: ajax.googleapis.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (...)
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Referer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743915/does-cdn-know-which-website-the-client-is-visiting-when-fetching-jquery-min-js-o
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Reporting which site it came from using the referer:

```
Referer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743915/does-cdn-know-which-website-the-client-is-visiting-when-fetching-jquery-min-js-o
```

Comment: are you sure ?
you send referer when you click.
if i place a photo (hot linking) on my site , the jpg doesn't send any data about my site...

Comment: Yes, all the page's assets are loaded with the proper Referer header.  I refreshed this page, and the following file `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js` was loaded with the following header `Referer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743915/does-cdn-know-which-website-the-client-is-visiting-when-fetching-jquery-min-js-o`

Comment: how did you check it ?
and also if i already have jquery.min.js from google CDN cached in my browser , can google track all my activity on stackoverflow.com or it's just informed once that I visited the site first time ?

Comment: I just tested. Linked a photo from other server and domain. This is what I found in apache access_log file: xx.xx.xx.xx - - [10/Jun/2015:00:54:32 +0200] "GET /img/538.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 74157 , looks like no referer here. Are you guys sure the referer is being sent with linked resources ? I think it needs a click.

Comment: @K3N where is the screenshot from ?

Comment: @knm from Firefox/39 console. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/KM2Icxj.png) is one for linked images.

Comment: @knm the apache access_log file only shows the http GET protocol command there and its response status (200 = OK), not the http *header fields*. You need to look at the rest of the request header too.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, they know the URL of the page which requested the resource (e.g. by looking at the `Referer` header). So they could track what websites requested a certain resource. The only exception is when an HTTPS page requests a resource over a non-secure connection. In that case the `Referer` won't be set, but the `Origin` header could be of some help anyway.

Tracking individual users could certainly be done, but it's impractical for a number of reasons:

1. CDN resources are meant to be heavily cached by browsers, so they will be requested and downloaded once for many different page views, making "passive" stats bogus.
2. Forcing the user to download the resource for each page visited makes CDNs pointless, slows down the navigation for no reason and overloads CDN's bandwidth. This was the technique used by long-dead views counters on GeoCities pages from the 90s (sigh).
3. Tracking users requires setting an identifying cookie at least. This adds complexity to the web service (since it can't be a simple file server anymore) and latency to the response time, since the UID has to be looked up in some form of DB or newly generated. Etags could be abused as well, with the same issues of cookies.
4. As an alternative, using query string parameters could work, but requires collaboration from the target page, which has to include the UID as a parameter to each request, which means URLs cannot be hard-coded. I guess this is not the case you are talking about.

To sum up, a CDN *could* track your visitors, but the downsides of doing so are actually larger than the hypothetical gain, assuming the performance and the linked profitability is the main goal of running a CDN. If analytics are more valuable than performance or economy of operation, like it could be for a free CDN, then one could sacrifice performance for gaining insights by applying points 2 and 3.

At that point, one would have to demonstrate the soundness of collected stats in order to be able to sell them for any marketing purpose. Besides, the nature of the files usually served by CDNs make them quite uninteresting. For instance, I don't see a lot of profitability in knowing how many people use a certain version of jQuery out there.

Comment: so why CDNs are free ? where is their profit ? bandwidth costs, right ?

Comment: @knm almost no free CDN is the central part of a business. Some are run as a side project "because they can" or because it benefits them in the first place (like Google CDN, which is used by all of Google's websites), some others are sponsored by donations (like jQuery CDN). Microsoft and Amazon Cloudfront both provide paid access to some forms of CDN, which means the owner of a certain website/webapp pays for increased availability and delivery speed. I am not very versed in the economical part of such a business, so there might be room for profitability, indeed. Mine are technical reasons :)

Answer (score 1):

`<meta name="referrer" content="same-origin">`
in this case no referrer will be sent to the CDN